# CodeVision AVR: Cannot read object file

Tags: c, avr

I've just installed CodeVision AVR and create a new project. The code compiled successfully, but when I build the project I get this error:

"Can't read file: E:\prjpath\Obj\test.obj."
test.obj is existed in the expected directory.

I've tested the following solutions (but did not work):

- Run as administrator
- The directory must be without any space character.
- No directory (folder) name can be longer than 8 characters.

Please mention that the problem appears after restarting the PC. The project build successfully when I've just installed CodeVision AVR (before system restart).